# Office js Dialog issue in Excel 16.13

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-js-helpers

I was using the following function from Office js library to display a Excel dialog -

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(startAddress, options, callback)
```

On closing the dialog box programatically and trying to open it again , it is showing the following error -

> Error code - 12007 .A dialog box is already opened from the task pane.
>   A task pane add-in can only have one dialog box open at a time.

The issue is persisting at `Microsoft Excel 16.13`. It works fine on all the previous versions of Excel.

Comment: How are you closing it programmatically?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - I am using the following code - 

Office.context.ui.messageParent("Y");

The following event handler is also added to handle the message - 
 
   var dialogWindow = asyncResult.value;
   dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,function(asyncResult){
     
     dialogWindow.close();
   });

Comment: The dialog window is also getting closed. But when we are executing the function the next time. The above mentioned error pops up.

Comment: It most likely has to do with context getting lost or references being left hanging around causing the dialog api to think there is still an active window. If you can edit your question and include snippets on how you're opening the API and wiring up the even handles, it will help narrow down what is happening.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - This is the sample code that we used -

Comment: declare var Office;
declare var $;
declare const Excel: any;

//open dialog function
openDialog= function(){
  console.log("in open dialog function");
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:4200', 
          {height:20, width:20}, function(asyncResult){
            console.log(asyncResult.value);                  
          }
        );
}

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - Any lead on this would be very helpful.